# Strange behavior after fseek() has worked

Tags: c, debugging, fseek

I've came across a strange behavior. While debugging, when a `while`-loop loops at first time: after going though `/* "data-url" */` and `/* "data-author" */` parts of code I have the next result in `Debugging windows -> Watches`:

***(I'm using Code::Blocks IDE, Ubuntu 13.04)***

The length of `dataUrl_tempString` is **8** bytes, 
the length of `dataAuthor_tempString` is **11** bytes,
the length of `dataName_tempString` is **9** bytes...

[image: 1st pic]

But after going through `/* data-name */` part of code I have the the result that confuses me:

[image: 2nd pic]

**Now they are not of size 8, 11 and 9 bytes!**

**What is the matter?**

Could you help me finding the reason of such behavior?

---

Here is the code of that function:

```
int SubString_Search(char *fnameNew, char *strUrl, char *strAuthor, char *strName) {

    FILE *fp;
    FILE *ofp_erase;
    FILE *ofp;
    char ch_buf;
    int count = 0;

    char dataUrl[8] = "";
    char dataAuthor[11] = "";
    char dataName[9] = "";
    char *dataUrl_tempString = &dataUrl[0];
    char *dataAuthor_tempString = &dataAuthor[0];
    char *dataName_tempString = &dataName[0];


    if( (fp = fopen("output_temp.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("File could not be opened.\n");
        return (-1);
    }
    else {
        /* Erasing 'NEW' file if exists */
        ofp_erase = fopen(fnameNew, "w");
        fclose(ofp_erase);
    }



    ofp = fopen(fnameNew, "a");
    rewind(fp);

    while(!feof(fp)) {

        /* "data-url" */
        fread(dataUrl_tempString, 8, sizeof(char), fp);
        if(memcmp(dataUrl_tempString, strUrl) == 0) {
            fseek(fp, 2, SEEK_CUR);     // going up to required place to copy a string
            while( (ch_buf = getc(fp)) != '"') {
                fputc(ch_buf, ofp);
            }
            fputc('\n', ofp);
        }
        fseek(fp, -8, SEEK_CUR);


        /* "data-author" */
        fread(dataAuthor_tempString, 11, sizeof(char), fp);
        if(memcmp(dataAuthor_tempString, strAuthor) == 0) {
            fseek(fp, 2, SEEK_CUR);     // going up to required place to copy a string
            while( (ch_buf = getc(fp)) != '"') {
                fputc(ch_buf, ofp);
            }
            fputc(' ', ofp);
            fputc('-', ofp);
            fputc(' ', ofp);
        }
        fseek(fp, -11, SEEK_CUR);


        /* "data-name" */
        fread(dataName_tempString, 9, sizeof(char), fp);
        if(memcmp(dataName_tempString, strName) == 0) {
            fseek(fp, 2, SEEK_CUR);     // going up to required place to copy a string
            while( (ch_buf = getc(fp)) != '"') {
                fputc(ch_buf, ofp);
            }
            //fputc() not needed
        }
        fseek(fp, -8, SEEK_CUR); // jumping over 1 symbol from the beginning: `-8` instead of `-9`...


        count++;
        if(count == 5)
            break;
    }

    rewind(fp);
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(ofp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Side note: `while (!feof(fp))` is [almost always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/1256452).  Here it's wrong-but-harmless, acting like `while (1)` (`fseek` clears the `feof` indicator) but your `break` takes care of it.

Comment: OT: `sizeof(Char)` is always `1`. Always check the outcome of system calls.

Comment: @alk, I've read one book about **C** and have just began reading S.McConnell "Code Complete" and I think I'll follow your advise in the future... But not now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like to change the call to

```
int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

to become calls to

```
int memcmp(const void *s1, const void *s2, size_t n);
```

This shall fix the issue, as long as you do not use other members of the `str*()` family of function on those (non `0`-terminated) `char` arrays.

**Note**: However `memcmp()` **always** compares the number of characters passed as 3rd parameter (`n`). This might not be what you want.

---

**Update:**

Alternativly (as mixure of both calls above) there also is:

```
int strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n);
```

Which compares up until it finds a `0`-terminator in either `s1` or `s2` and to a maximum of `n` characters.

Comment: So `memcmp()` works to arrays as `strcmp()` to strings does?
 I want to compare arrays as strings..

Comment: @YulianKhlevnoy: Please see the note I just added to my answer.

Comment: And what is the *3rd parameter*?

Comment: @YulianKhlevnoy: The number of bytes to be compared. Also so please see `man memset`.

Comment: Here it is! These two functions are equal is some sense. So, if I compare "data-url" and "data-url" it will return `0` (as `strcmp()`) does. Thanks!

Comment: @H2CO3, I've been reading a lot for the last time, so my brains are of ~100 degrees above zero... But I follow your advise every time (Now I've looked for `memcmp()` reference).

Comment: @YulianKhlevnoy Very good! I know what you are talking about :)

Comment: @YulianKhlevnoy: Your IDE cheats you. It can not handle non-`0`-terminated "strings".

Comment: You are storing the string in successive locations in memory that is initially all set to zeros. From the output you show you can deduce that the strings are stored in the order url, name, author. Prove this to yourself by changing the strings (so they each start with something different). Once the "middle string" (name) is used, the only string termination is at the end of the block (after author). Give yourself more space. Anything that is asked to display a string looks for the `'\0'` and keeps going until it finds it (or segfaults).

Answer (score 5):

A string needs to have space for a `'\0'` termination - you only allocated 8 bytes for a string with 8 characters (which therefore needs 9 bytes minimum). Depending on what follows in memory, you will get unpredictable results.

Comment: Yeah - I knew straight off it was going to be that or strlen().

Comment: Do you mean `dataUrl_tempString` variable? I manipulate them as an array, not a string.

Comment: `dataUrl_tempstring` points to `dataUrl[8]` - therefore you only "own" the first eight bytes. A string needs a termination. You don't have space for that - so anything could happen.

Comment: Uh, I've been using `strcmp` to `dataUrl_tempString`...
I'll remove this error and if it helps, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @YulianKhlevnoy Use `strncmp()` or `memcmp()` instead.